# String match excluding brackets

Tags: perl, brackets

The below two strings are exactly same, but I am unable to match using regex? Can some one help me in this?

```
$x="Enzyme(s)"; $y="Enzyme(s)";

if ($x =~ /^$y$/){print "String Matches"};
```

Answer (score 1):

use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html):

```
my $x="Enzyme(s)";
my $y="Enzyme(s)";
$y = quotemeta($y);
if ($x =~ /^$y$/){print "String Matches"};
```

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses in your match string, $y, are being interpreted as a grouping or capture.  They need to be "escaped" so that they can be treated as normal characters.

Put the following code after your assignment of $y.

```
$y =~ s/\(/\\(/g;  # escape left parens
$y =~ s/\)/\\)/g;  # escape right parens
```

The 's' is for 'substitution'.
The 'g' is for 'global' replacement.  I.e., replace all occurrences in the string.

Comment: You're welcome!  (Welcome to StackOverflow!  At this point, you should 'Accept' my answer to encourage me...  ;^)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `quotemeta` as M42 already mentioned, or to avoid an extra line of code and a permanent change of $y variable, you can use the `\Q...\E` in the regex which disable all pattern metacharacters within the range:

```
my $x="Enzyme(s)";
my $y="Enzyme(s)";
if ($x =~ /^\Q$y\E$/){print "String Matches"};
```